# log4j fatal level logging required

Tags: java, log4j

This is my log4j.xml. i want only `FATAL` log from package `com.xyz.rest` should print to `/LOGS/Acb/d.log` file.

But i can see `Debug` level logs as well in file. Why log4j is printing `Debug` level logs from `com.xyz.rest` package.

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">

<appender name="Def" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="/LOGS/Acb/d.log"/>
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10000KB"/>
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10"/>

        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
        </layout>
</appender>
<logger name="com.xyz.rest">
        <logger value="fatal"/>
        <appender-ref ref="Def"/>
</logger>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because with the following code you are **adding** another log `level` to your `com.xyz.rest` package which is not removing the `debug` level which your package inherits from parents:

```
<logger name="com.xyz.rest">
        <logger value="fatal"/>
        <appender-ref ref="Def"/>
</logger>
```

What you need is to set the `additivity` to false so that rather than adding another log level, you will set the log level:

```
<logger name="com.xyz.rest" additivity="false">
        <logger value="fatal"/>
        <appender-ref ref="Def"/>
</logger>
```

More information can be found [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html).

Not sure but it might also be necessary to enclose the `<logger></logger>` tags in `<loggers></loggers>` tag